# Configure Logback to email entire log for a request if some error was logged

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I'm using MDC and a key `"requestId"` to keep track of incoming requests. I would now like to use `SMTPAppender` to send me a mail with the entire log of a given request if any line is on error level.

I know I can use an MDC discriminator to group the log lines after request id. The problem is that the `SMTPAppender` emails me the log for the request upon *the first error*. I would like subsequent log-lines for that request to be included as well.

I don't mind putting a marker after each request (but I'd prefer to put that on TRACE level). I.e. after each request, I don't mind doing

```
logger.trace(MarkerFactory.getMarker("END_OF_REQUEST"), "End of request");
```

to "flush" the email.

(I've tried creating my own evaluator, but I can't make it play well with the discriminator.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it as follows:

```
public class MyEvaluator extends ContextAwareBase
                         implements EventEvaluator<ILoggingEvent> {

    private String name;
    private boolean started;
    private Set<String> requestIdsWithErrors = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean evaluate(ILoggingEvent event) {

        String requestId = MDC.get("requestId");
        boolean result = false;

        if (event.getLevel().levelInt >= Level.ERROR_INT)
            requestIdsWithErrors.add(requestId);

        Marker marker = event.getMarker();
        if (marker != null && marker.getName().equals("END_OF_REQUEST"))
            result = requestIdsWithErrors.remove(requestId);

        return result;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public boolean isStarted() { return started; }
    public void start() { started = true; }
    public void stop() { started = false; }
}
```

I wish I could leverage `SMTPAppender`s discriminator mechanism (and replace the `requestIdsWithErrors` set with a `boolean`). If any one knows how to do this, I'd appreciate if that some one posted an answer...